# Dataframe Append vs pandas Concat

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, append

I am trying to append to a dataframe, and it is working, however I am having to use an old version of python in order to do so. I have not used pd.concat that much in the past. I am unsure of how to format my code so it outputs the same dataframe it does with append.

```
def new_df(df):
    Employee = []
    PayItem = ['E01', 'E40', 'E41', 'E42']
    Hours = []
    Dollars = []
    new = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Key', 'PayItem', 'Hours', 'Dollars'])

    Employee = df.loc[0:27,'Employee Number']
    Key = Employee.values.tolist()
    Hours = df.loc[0:27,'Working Hours']

    for i in range(28):
        ok = []
        ok.append(np.nan)
        ok.append(df.loc[i, 'Product Commissions'])
        ok.append(df.loc[i, 'Membership Commissions'])
        ok.append(df.loc[i, 'Tips'])
        Dollars.append(ok)

    for i in range(len(Dollars)):
        for j in range(0,1):
            new = new.append({'Key' : Employee[i], 'PayItem' : PayItem[0], 'Hours': Hours[i],  'Dollars': Dollars[i][j]}, ignore_index=True)
            new = new.append({'Key' : Employee[i], 'PayItem' : PayItem[1], 'Hours': ' ', 'Dollars': Dollars[i][j+1]}, ignore_index=True)
            new = new.append({'Key' : Employee[i], 'PayItem' : PayItem[2], 'Hours': ' ', 'Dollars': Dollars[i][j+2]}, ignore_index=True)
            new = new.append({'Key' : Employee[i], 'PayItem' : PayItem[3], 'Hours': ' ', 'Dollars': Dollars[i][j+3]}, ignore_index=True)
        
    return new
```

I tried using pandas concat however I am formatting it incorrectly and not getting the same outcome.

Comment: Use `new = pd.concat([new,pd.DataFrame([{'Key' : Employee[i], 'PayItem' : PayItem[0], 'Hours': Hours[i],  'Dollars': Dollars[i][j]}])])` then `new= pd.concat([new,pd.DataFrame([{'Key' : Employee[i], 'PayItem' : PayItem[1], 'Hours': ' ', 'Dollars': Dollars[i][j+1]}])])` etc....

Answer (score 0):

`pd.concat()`concatenates two panda dataframes. So you need to set up a dataframe first with your new entries.Building `ok` is probably easier by hand. So like this:

```
def new_df(df):
    PayItem = ['E01', 'E40', 'E41', 'E42']
    new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Key', 'PayItem', 'Hours', 'Dollars'])

    Employee = df.loc[0:27, 'Employee Number']
    Hours = df.loc[0:27, 'Working Hours']

    for i in range(28):
        ok = [np.nan, df.loc[i, 'Product Commissions'], df.loc[i, 'Membership Commissions'], df.loc[i, 'Tips']]
        Dollars = ok

        data = {'Key': [Employee[i]] * len(PayItem),
            'PayItem': PayItem,
            'Hours': [Hours[i]] * len(PayItem),
            'Dollars': Dollars}

        new = pd.concat([new, pd.DataFrame(data)], ignore_index=True)

return new
```

Comment: It would be more efficient frst to form all the data (eg List of Dictionaries) then just once form the new DF then a single concat.